# How to let Swift derive specified type for decoding JSON

Tags: json, swift, generics, decodable

I find myself often using `try JSONDecoder().decode(Foo.self, from: Baz.foo.data)` and I don't really like it, cause in my case I know that `Baz.foo.data` will always be able to be casted to `Foo` as well as `Baz.bar.data` - to `Bar`. I want to simplify the code by defining types I want to get after parsing in `Baz` itself, so that it becomes something like this: `try JSONDecoder().decode(from: Baz.foo.data)` or even better - `Baz.foo.decoded`. The code I came up with is the following:

```
struct Foo: Decodable {
    var foo: String
}

struct Bar: Decodable {
    var bar: String
}

enum Baz<T> where T: Decodable {
    case foo, bar
    
    var decoded: T {
        try! JSONDecoder().decode(self.type, from: self.data)
    }
    
    var type: T.Type {
        switch self {
        case .foo:
            return Foo.self as! T.Type
        case .bar:
            return Bar.self as! T.Type
        }
        
    }
    
    var data: Data {
        switch self {
        case .foo:
            return #"{"foo": "Foo string"}"#.data(using: .utf8)!
        case .bar:
            return #"{"bar": "Bar string"}"#.data(using: .utf8)!
        }
    }
}
```

But to use it I still would need to manually specify `T`, namely: `Baz<Foo>.foo.decoded`. Is there a way to let Swift specify it by itself?

Comment: Why do you even have `Baz` that returns `Data` - why not decode `Foo`, and `Bar`, and just have `Baz` hold the actual object via associated values? You might be asking a question about an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - if you explained a bit about the purpose of `Baz` objects, we might be able to give you a better suggestion

Comment: well, fair point, will also work, but I still need to manually type in all the types. Your solution would be pretty optimal if each case would be responsible for its unique type. But if there are multiple cases, that decode same type from different `Data`s then you still would have repetitions instead of writing `case .foo, .bar: return SomeType.self`

Comment: And yes, it is an XY problem, but I’m more interested in the solution itself, than in how to solve my problem. It’s just an interesting case I ran into and would like to know how Swift can be used. But to make it clear: I have an `enum` that holds all possible mock variants I have for testing. `data` parameter returns me `Data` from a specific `.json` file, which is unique for each `case`. So when I need the mock object somewhere in the project I use `try JSONDecoder().decode(Foo.self, from: Baz.foo.data)`